# why keypress event is not worked?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

please help solve the problem. i make template, view and run them.

html:

```
<div class="space" id="space"></div>
```

tpl:

```
<script type="text/template" id="spaceTpl">
  <div class="container main_container">
    <div class="row">
    gfdgdfgdfg<br>gfdgdfgdfg<br>gfdgdfgdfg<br>gfdgdfgdfg<br>gfdgdfgdfg<br>gfdgdfgdfg<br>gfdgdfgdfg<br>gfdgdfgdfg<br>
    </div>      
  </div>
</script>
```

view:

```
window.APP = window.APP || {};
APP.SpaceView = Backbone.View.extend({  

  initialize: function() {   
    this.render();
  },    

  template: _.template($('#spaceTpl').html()),

  render: function() {    
    this.$el.html(this.template());  
    return this;
  }, 

  events: {
    'click': 'move',
    'keypress': 'move',
    'keydown': 'move'
  }, 

  move: function(e) {  console.log(222)
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (code === 13) {
      console.log('sdsd');
    }
  }     

});
```

init:

```
var app = new APP.SpaceView({el: '#space'});
```

needed after press any key in console display '222'. but nothing happens.

i.e. keypress-handler is not worked. why??

https://jsfiddle.net/9t1cwfrv/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works if you set it to use on a focused element. If you don't want to focus you can use it on `body` element or `document`.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/9t1cwfrv/21/

Answer (score 1):

in your template set `tabindex="1"`

`<div class="container main_container" tabindex="1" >`

https://jsfiddle.net/4ga489zy/1/

Comment: I'd recommend setting `tabIndex="-1"` to avoid the user tabbing into that element accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

`keypress` and `keydown` will not work if the element is not focused.

It makes sense in an input, or you can try setting it up on the document element:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    console.log(e, code); 
});
```

Backbone `input` example:

```js
var Input = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'input',
  events: {
    'keypress': 'press'
  },
  press: function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    console.log( code );
  }
});

(new Input()).$el.appendTo( document.body );
```

```html
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.3/backbone-min.js'></script>
```